# append text with echo without new line

Tags: shell, text-processing, io-redirection, echo

I want to append text to file like `echo "abc" >>file.txt`.

But this add `abc` after new line

How can I add `abc` in the end of file with echo without new line?

Comment: The file already has a newline, you are just adding after it. So you will have to replace the newline character from the last line, with “abc”.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Your question is good; it would have been better if you specified examples of the content of your file (before addition, what you get after addition, what you wanted instead). I say this because one of the answers is how to add `abc` without a final newline, which (after reading your question attentively) does not seem to be what you want.

Answer (score 50):

Assuming that the file does not already end in a newline and you simply want to append some more text without adding one, you can use the `-n` argument, e.g.

```
echo -n "some text here" >> file.txt
```

However, some UNIX systems do not provide this option; if that is the case you can use `printf`, e.g.

```
printf %s "some text here" >> file.txt
```

(the initial `%s` argument being to guard against the additional text having `%` formatting characters in it)

From `man echo` (on macOS High Sierra):

> **-n**
>
> > Do not print the trailing newline character.  This may also be           achieved by appending `'\c'` to the end of the string, as is done by           iBCS2 compatible systems.  Note that this option as well as the           effect of `'\c'` are implementation-defined in IEEE Std 1003.1-2001           ("POSIX.1") as amended by Cor. 1-2002.  Applications aiming for           maximum portability are strongly encouraged to use `printf(1)` to           suppress the newline character.

Comment: It quite obviously _does_ end with a newline.  `echo -n` would put no newline at the end of `abc`, but `abc` would still be preceded by a newline, which is what the user wants to avoid.

Comment: @Kusalananda My answer was more using the assumption that the OP would try to change their process such that the spurious `\n` didn't show up in the first place. More options are better, especially when they don't involve having to rewrite the entire file every time a change happens (which can get rather slow and run in polynomial time if it's done repeatedly).

Answer (score 25):

`echo "abc" >>file.txt` puts a newline *after* `abc`, not before. If you end up with `abc` on its own line, that means that the newline before `abc` was already present in `file.txt`.

Note that it is perfectly normal for a text file to end in a newline. On unix, a line consists of a sequence of characters other than null⁰ or newline followed by a newline.<sup>1</sup> Therefore any non-empty text file ends with a newline character.

If you want to add text to the last line of a file, then you can't do it with `>>`, because this always appends to the file, so it always writes after the last newline. Instead you need a tool that is capable of modifying an existing file. For example, you can use [sed](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html):

```
sed '$ s/$/abc/' file.txt >file.txt.new && mv file.txt.new file.txt
```

In the sed command, the first `$` means “do the following command only on the last line”, the command `s/REGEX/REPLACEMENT/` replaces REGEX by REPLACEMENT, and the regular expression `$` matches at the end of the line.

Linux's sed command has a built-in feature to automate this create-new-file-and-replace sequence, so you can shorten that to

```
sed -i '$ s/$/abc/' file.txt
```

⁰  <sub>That's a null byte, which ASCII calls NUL and Unicode calls U+0000. Text processing programs may or may not cope with this character.</sub> 
<sup>1</sup>  <sub>See the definitions of *Text File*, *Line*, and *Newline Character* in the "Definitions" section of the *Base Definitions* chapter of IEEE 1003.1-2008:2016.</sub>

Comment: Is your second paragraph meant to imply that a file which doesn't end with a newline is not a text file? E.g. if I take an existing ASCII text file which ends with a new line and append a single byte `0x41` (ASCII `'A'`), it's technically no longer a text file? If so, I'd suggest emphasizing that point since it's kind of an unintuitive definition; if not, a slight change in wording might help avoid the confusion.

Comment: @DavidZ: That is the standard definition of a text file in Unixland.  IIRC it's even in POSIX somewhere.

Comment: @Kevin Interesting, I'd never heard that before. Well, even if it is standard, I do think it's kind of unintuitive.

Answer (score 18):

I don't think it's possible with `echo` command, use the following **`sed`** approach instead:

```
sed -i '$ s/$/abc/' file.txt
```

- `-i` - modify the file *inplace*
- `$` - indicate the last record/line
- `s/$/abc/` - substitute the end of the line `$` with substring `abc` (for the last record)

Comment: Note that "in place" doesn't really mean in place. It means "write the edited content to a temporary named file alongside the existing file and then replace it". You can prove this by looking at the inodes with `date >file; ls -i file; sed -i 's/201/ZZZ/' file; ls -i file`

Comment: @roaima, I'm aware about sed changing inode number.

Comment: I thought you would have been, but i was concerned that with your emphasis of _inplace_ the OP night think it could be used to avoid double disk space use, eg with a large file.

Comment: @roaima, *night think* -> might think ...

Comment: What if I want to replace abc with a variable ? Using `'$ s/$/$1/'` prints `$1`

Answer (score 13):

If you have the `truncate` command and your text file has NL as its last character you can remove it and then append your text like this:

```
truncate --size -1 file.txt
echo "abc" >>file.txt
```

(Note that `truncate` cares nothing about file content, and in this example simply reduces the file size by one byte. If your last character is not a single byte, ie it's a multi-byte "wide" character then you will introduce corruption.)

Answer (score 5):

What you want is to add it at the end of the last line, so just before the delimiter of that last line, so just before the last character of the file.

With `ksh93`, you can do:

```
echo abc 1<> file >#((EOF - 1))
```

Where `1<>` is the standard operator to open a file in read+write mode (and more importantly *without truncation*) on stdout and `>#((...))` is a ksh93-specific *seeking* operator (here to seek to before the last byte). Note that `echo` writes `abc<newline>` where the `a` overwrites the newline that was there and `echo` adds its own newline.

The `zsh` equivalent:

```
zmodload zsh/system
{sysseek -w end -u 1 -1 && echo abc} 1<> file
```

Though for a more exact equivalent, you'd also need to print an error message upon failure to seek:

```
zmodload zsh/system
if sysseek -w end -u 1 -1; then
  echo abc
else
  syserror -p "$0: $LINENO: seek: "
fi 1<> file
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably a [UUOC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat) but you could also do:

```
echo "$(cat file.txt)abc" >file.txt
```

As Gilles points out this command is limited:

> This mostly works, but not if there is sometimes a blank line at the end of the file and a blank line immediately before. E.g. a file with a fixed number of lines, where the last line is initially empty and is extended over time, and the next-to-last-line may sometimes be empty.

Additionally be wary of using `cat` on files you are not familiar with:

- [CVE-2003-0063](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2003-0063)
- [CVE-2008-2383](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2008-2383)
- [CVE-2010-2713](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2010-2713)
- [CVE-2003-0020](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2003-0020)
- [CVE-2012-3515](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=CVE-2012-3515)
- [More](https://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/archive/1/508830/100/0/threaded)

**Conclusion**:

Use [sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412837/237982)

Comment: This mostly works, but not if there is sometimes a blank line at the end of the file and a blank line immediately before. E.g. a file with a fixed number of lines, where the last line is initially empty and is extended over time, and the next-to-last-line may sometimes be empty.

Comment: Should I delete it?  I definitely think Roman/your answer is the proper way to go but I know I personally like seeing alternatives, and OP did ask for `echo` :p

Comment: Also this puts the entire file on the command line

Comment: @n.caillou huh?  This will not print anything to STDOUT.

Comment: Well, none of those vulnerabilities are really related to `cat`, but to issues with arbitrary escape sequences being sent to the terminal.

Comment: +1 for teaching me about the existence of UUOC