# Append grep match count number on same line as filename

Tags: text-processing, grep

I want to search for the match count of a specific word/pattern in all files below a certain directory. However, I want the number to appear directly after the filename.

I did the following but it writes the count to a new line instead of the last line

```
grep -rc "WORD" /home/user/data >> file
```

Actual output

```
foo
12
```

Desired output:

```
foo12
```

Answer (score 1):

With `>> file`, the file is opened on stdout in append mode. So any output goes at the end of the file.

`grep` writes `12\n`. Your file contained `foo\n` beforehand. So you get `foo\n12\n`. To get `foo12\n`, you'd need not to output at the end, but at the last byte before then end, to overwrite that `\n` with `12\n`.

Some shells have operators for that.

With `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/system
if sysseek -u 1 -w end -1; then
  grep -c WORD /home/user/data
else
  syserror -p "Can't seek to just before the end: "
fi 1<> file
```

With `ksh93`:

```
grep -c WORD /home/user/data 1<> file >#((EOF - 1))
```

`<>` is the redirection operator that opens files in read+write mode. Here, we don't care about the *read* part, but we use `<>` as contrary to `>`, it doesn't truncate files.

In any case, that is not an *append* mode. You'll see a difference if some other process also writes to the file or truncates it at the same time (unlikely to be a problem in your case).

Another approach could be to truncate the file to remove the trailing `\n`, and then open the file in *append* mode.

With GNU `truncate`:

```
truncate -s -1 file && grep -c WORD /home/user/data >> file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed to append at the end of the last line:

```
sed -i '$ s/$/'$(grep -rc "WORD" /home/user/data)'/' file
```

See also: [append text with echo without new line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412835/append-text-with-echo-without-new-line)